# getting sps and pps from CMSampleBufferRef

Tags: video-streaming, video-processing, video-encoding, ios8

i push image from camera to videoToolBox encoder with new API 
and get encoded CMSampleBufferRef from encoder callback

i need these sps and pts for CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateFromH264ParameterSets
to config decoder

could anyone help/guide me ? ) THX

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty easy to do it the other way round, the relevant function is `CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetH264ParameterSetAtIndex` and would be used something like

```
CMFormatDescriptionRef format = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer);
size_t spsSize, ppsSize;
size_t parmCount;
const uint8_t* sps, *pps;

CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetH264ParameterSetAtIndex(format, 0, &sps, &spsSize, &parmCount, nullptr );
CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetH264ParameterSetAtIndex(format, 1, &pps, &ppsSize, &parmCount, nullptr );
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract the 'avcC' element of the 'SampleDescriptionExtensionAtoms' Dictionary, then use 'CFDataGetLength' and 'CFDataGetBytePtr' to get a direct pointer to the avcC structure, this structure can then be parsed in teh following way:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct AVCC {
    uint8_t  version;
    uint8_t  profile_idc;
    uint8_t  compatibility;
    uint8_t  level_idc;
    uint8_t  nalu_size  : 2;// indicates the length in bytes of the NALUnitLength field in an AVC video sample or AVC parameter set sample of the associated stream **minus one**
    uint8_t  reserved1  : 6;
    uint8_t  numSPS     : 5;// length size minus one
    uint8_t  reserved2  : 3;
    uint16_t SPSlen; 
    uint8_t  pSPS[15];      // Sequence parameter set
    uint8_t  numPPS;
    uint16_t PPSlen;
    uint32_t pPPS[1];       // Picture parameter set
};
#pragma pack(pop)

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    AVCC* pAVCC = (AVCC*)g_pAVCC;

    pAVCC->SPSlen = ((pAVCC->SPSlen & 0x00FF) << 8) | ((pAVCC->SPSlen & 0xFF00) >> 8);
    pAVCC->PPSlen = ((pAVCC->PPSlen & 0x00FF) << 8) | ((pAVCC->PPSlen & 0xFF00) >> 8);


    uint8_t* pSPS = (uint8_t*)pAVCC->pSPS;
    uint8_t* pPPS = (uint8_t*)pAVCC->pPPS;

    ...

    return 0;
}
```